# not working batch file to rewrite txt file

Tags: string, batch-file, formatting, txt

Im creating a file with devcon utility in order to list all usb devices that were connected to a PC since I need to delete hidden devices(not in use). In this moment I want to rewrite the strings in the created file but adding "@ to the begining and " till the endo of the string, so this would be an example

devcon obtained string

```
USB\VID_8087&PID_0025\7&21809D95&0&2
```

desired rewrite

```
"@USB\VID_8087&PID_0025\7&21809D95&0&2"
```

not sure if can be done in this same lines or if it needs to be added separately

```
setlocal
cmd /c "for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('findstr /c:"USB\VID" DevicesExist.txt') do @for %%a in (%%I) do @echo %%a"| findstr /c:"USB\VID">DevicesExist2.txt
```

any ideas?, thank you

Comment: I am confused on three things.  1) Why are you using `CMD /C`? Why are you using a second `FOR` command? 3) Why are you using a second `FINDSTR` command that is doing the same thing as the first?  You make no attempt in your code to even output the data like you want it.  I don't see any spot in your code where you attempt to output a leading quote and at symbol.

Answer (score 0):

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

(
FOR /f "tokens=1delims= " %%b IN ('devcon findall *^|find "USB\VID"') DO (
 ECHO "@%%b"

)
)>>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

Not really sure why your code is so complex or why you haven't posted a small sample of your `DevicesExist.txt` file.

This code executes `devcon` and appends the processed extracted data to a destination file. Use `>` in place of `>>` to replace any existing content of the destination file with the output from this batch.